# How to get start point of numbers in sequence and handle errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let me start with an example,

```
array([  1,   6,  12,  14,  16,  18,  21,  23,  24,  27,  29,  54,  55,
        56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,
        70,  71,  72,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  81,  82,  83,  84,
        85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,
        98,  99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111,
       112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124,
       125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 138,
       139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152,
       153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166,
       167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 177, 178])
```

> **Ideal Output**: 54 *(forward)*, 175 *(backward)*

**Conditions to satisfy :**

I need to find the first number from where its sequential in order for up-to 5 digits, for ex: from 54 onward the numbers are sequential in order (i.e., 54, 55, 56, 57, 58) (5 digits).

I require the same in reverse order (i., 175, 174, 173, 172, 171) (5 digits) from point 175 its sequential in order.

**Update:** I forgot to mention, in some cases I need a variable to assign the error that is acceptable.

> For example, lets say the `error_accepted = 1` and `error_difference(upto) = 1`, then if the values are
> 54, 56, 57, 58, 59 can be accepted. The output is still 54. Else, if
> `error_accepted = 2 and error_difference (upto) = 3`, then if the values are 54, 58, 59, 61, 62 can also
> be accepted. The output is still 54.

I tried to do something, the logic is not correct so please do excuse the code I have written.

```
# excuse the code, the logic ain't correct. 
start_ix_cnt = 0
start_ix_indices = None

counter_start = 0
counter = 0

for ix in matching_indexes:
    if start_ix_indices is None and start_ix_cnt == 0:
        start_ix_indices = list(range(1, 178))
        start_ix_cnt += 1
    else:
        if ix == start_ix_indices[start_ix_cnt]:
            counter += 1
            counter_start = start_ix_indices[0]
        else:
            start_ix_indices = list(range(ix, 178))
            start_ix_cnt = 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the values in the test list guaranteed to be distinct integers in ascending order?

Comment: @Joffan Yes, its always like that.

Comment: You only want the first element of the first series of up to 5 elements? You don't want 63, or 74 for example?

Comment: @HenryEcker No only the first element of the first series.

Comment: @HenryEcker I forgot to add one more point in the question. I have updated it. I also need a way to control errors that can be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Numpy you can split your array into sequential sets and find the sequence you're looking for using the length of set and/or its items:

```
In [96]: mask = np.diff(arr) != 1

In [97]: np.split(arr, np.where(mask)[0] + 1)
Out[97]: 
[array([1]),
 array([6]),
 array([12]),
 array([14]),
 array([16]),
 array([18]),
 array([21]),
 array([23, 24]),
 array([27]),
 array([29]),
 array([54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61]),
 array([63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72]),
 array([74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]),
 array([81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97,
        98, 99]),
 array([101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113,
        114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126,
        127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136]),
 array([138, 139]),
 array([141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153]),
 array([155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167,
        168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175]),
 array([177, 178])]
```

You can use following function in order to handle the accepted margin error:

```
In [98]: def sequencer(arr, err=1):
    ...:     mask = np.diff(arr) > err
    ...:     return np.split(arr, np.where(mask)[0] + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the sequencer seems to be working (fabulous code I never thought I could use numpy like that), but only one more problem if you see the update in question I actually need two arguments `error_accepted` and `error_difference`. Here the `err` in `sequencer` only seems to be acting as `error_difference`. Where as `error_accepted` is number of errors that is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# forward
for i in range(len(a)-5):
    if a[i+5] - a[i] <= 5 + upto:
        print(a[i])
        break

# reverse
for i in range(len(a)-1, 5, -1):
    if a[i] - a[i-5] <= 5 + upto:
        print(a[i])
        break
```

Comment: Really sorry for the delayed updation. I forgot to mention one thing in my question which I have updated just now. I also need a way to control the acceptable error in the order

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to it.

```
x = [  1,   6,  12,  14,  16,  18,  21,  23,  24,  27,  29,  54,  55,
        56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,
        70,  71,  72,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  81,  82,  83,  84,
        85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,
        98,  99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111,
       112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124,
       125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 138,
       139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152,
       153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166,
       167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 177, 178]
groups,count = [],0
def checkConsecutive(l):return (l == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)) or l.reverse() == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1))) and len(l) == 5
for numbers in x:
    groups.append(x[count:count+5])
    count += 1
check = lambda l:(l == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)) or l.reverse() == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1))) and len(l) == 5
newGroup = [seq for seq in groups if check]
print(newGroup)
```

Comment: Thank you. I also need a way to control the errors that is acceptable. I forgot to mention that point right when I posted the question so I updated it after realising. Can you check the question once more.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see that when creating this. My bad I'll create a solve.

Answer (score 1):

If code simplicity is important (rather than raw speed), you could write a function and call it twice, once with the test list and once with the reversed test list. This version is general purpose for required difference and length of sequence of such differences:

```py
def findseq(values, diff, threshold):
    seqstart = None
    prev = 0
    seqstate = -1 # => prev not valid
    for val in values:
        if val - prev == diff:
            if seqstate == 0:
                seqstart = prev
            seqstate += 1
            if seqstate == threshold:
                break
        else:
            seqstate = 0
        prev = val
        
    return seqstart

print(findseq(test_array,1,5))
print(findseq(reversed(test_array),-1,5))
```

Comment: Thank you. I also need a way to control the errors that is acceptable. I forgot to mention that point right when I posted the question so I updated it after realising. Can you check the question once more.

Comment: @user_12 Written to answer the original question with some generalization - does not cover the added "slightly broken sequence" modification. For the "broken sequence" option I would probably start by taking diffs of the whole array and looking for groups that include a certain number of such.